# Why can't I "distribute" an archive in another location ? ("credential" error)

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, credentials

I am working on an app and everything including "distribute" works fine: new versions of the app always appear in "Testflight".

I went to another location (other country, other ip address, but the same macbook) and was able to "archive" a new version of the app, but when I did "distribute" a "credentials" error came.
(I do not remember the complete error message, but it had to do with credentials)

I came back in the original location.
I picked from the "organiser" the archive which I had created in the other location, tried "distribute" again, and now it worked: the new version of the app arrived in Testflight.

I use xcode, where all of the credential - stuff is automatically dealt with.

Why can't I distribute an archive in another location as where I work originally?

I did not have time to try things in the other location.

Comment: I just got the "credential" error also in the original location, so it did not have anything to do with the location. I solved the problem in that I quitted Xcode and started it again. Then everything worked again, including "distribute".